# why is that we always get an extra column show in datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i have four columns specfied but why is that i always  see one  extra  column  shown in the output

this is my xaml code

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="492" Width="453">
        <sdk:DataGrid MinHeight="100" x:Name="dgCounty" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"   IsReadOnly="True"  Margin="5,5,5,0" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dgCounty_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"  SelectionMode="Extended"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="24" Height="24" Click="Details_Click">
                                <Image  x:Name="img" Source="Images/detail.JPG" Stretch="None"/>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="ID">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Name">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeFName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="MailID">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeMailID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

 </sdk:DataGrid>
```

**is there any setting that we need  to  do  to remove that extra  column?**

thanks in advance  for the  help.

Comment: This has never happened to me. What does this extra column represent ? Which data column ?

Comment: Are you doing any grouping?  If so that will add extra columns at the start and end.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about this last empty, quasi-column? If yes, the answer is here:

http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58939

Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the [ColumnWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnwidth%28VS.95%29.aspx) property of the DataGrid to *. An alternative approach is to set the [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.width%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of your last column to *.